# Sorting list with pipeline and without ls-lS command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, ls, sort

The Linux program ‘sort’ can sort a file, or the output from another program. How do I use sort to sort the output of the ls command by 1) file name 2) file size.

I know there are options of the ‘ls’ command to do this anyway, but I'm trying to use sort like this: ‘ls’ command to show size, options for the ‘sort’ command to control sorting and then combine using a pipe.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: We advise people to avoid parsing `ls` because `ls` is actually hard to parse. Once you get a filename with spaces in it, then you can no longer rely on `ls -l | awk '{print $5, $9}'`. If the filename contains a newline (a valid character), then it's an order of magnitude harder. For gory details see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: I found what I was after here (check step 3): https://www.baeldung.com/linux/list-by-size

Comment: Actually `ls -1` sorts by file names, so you don't need any sort. Likewise `ls -rS` sorts by size. Maybe explain why that isn't good for you. Student exercise?

Answer (score 2):

With [the GNU implementation of `stat`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/stat.1.html)¹, and assuming filenames don't contain newline characters, and that there's no file called `-` in the current directory you'd do

```bsh
stat -c '%s %n' -- * | sort -t' ' -k1,1n -k2
```

The sort keys:

- first by field 1 (size) numerically (ascending)
- next by fields 2-end (filename) lexically (ascending)

---

<sup>¹ beware `stat` is not a standard command and there exists several incompatible implementations</sup>

Answer (score 1):

File names on Unix-like systems are sequences of one or more (usually up to some limit) bytes other than 0 and the one that encoded `/`.

`sort` sorts lines, that is arrays of 0 or more (up to some limit with some implementations) *characters* other and newline (and NUL with some implementations) based on the sort key specification given on the command line.

The GNU implementation of `sort` (and its clones) can handle NULs on input as an extension over the standard and can also sort NUL-delimited records instead of lines (with the `-z` option).

You can have a byte == character mapping if you fix the locale to `C` (in effect, if you disable localisation).

The ast-open implementation of `ls` can get you close with for instance:

```
ls --format='%(size)d\t%(name)s'
```

However, that's newline delimited records instead of NUL-delimited records so can't work as newline is as valid a character as any in a file name.

You can't use `\0` in there to get a NUL, but you could make it:

```
ls --format='%(size)d\t%(name)s/'
```

And with the help of GNU `awk`, you could convert those `/<newline>` delimiters to NUL delimiters for GNU `sort -z`:

```
ls --format='%(size)d\t%(name)s' |
  LC_ALL=C gawk -v 'RS=/\n' -v 'ORS=\0' 1 |
  LC_ALL=C sort -zn |
  LC_ALL=C tr '\0' '\n'
```

(the `tr` in the end being for display only).

With GNU `ls`, you can't format the output like you want like with ast-open's (`find` or `stat` are the ones that do that in the GNU tool chest) but since version 9.0, you can use the `--zero` option to output records NUL-delimited.

With:

```
LC_ALL=C ls -go --zero
```

You get an output like:

```
<mode><spaces><links><spaces><size><space><t1><spaces><t2><spaces><t3><space><name><NUL>
```

So you would be able to extract size and name from that.

But that doesn't work for all types of files.

- for symlinks, instead of `<name>`, you get `<name><space>-><space><target-path>`
- for device files, instead of the `<size>`, you get `<major>,<spaces><minor>` device numbers.

GNU `ls` also has a `--dired` option which gives an output intended for `emacs`, with information about where each file name starts and ends in the output. That would help for symlinks, but not for device files, and you'd need additional work to use the `//DIRED//` offsets to extra the information and reformat it in a format suitable for sorting.

The output of `ls` is simply not meant to be post-processed.

Instead, you can use:

- `zsh` globs which can be sorted with arbitrary criteria
- GNU `find` with its `-printf` predicate
- zsh's, BSD's or GNU's `stat` (with incompatible API)
- Or higher level programming languages such as perl, ruby or python and their `stat()`/`lstat()`/`statx()`... APIs and built-in sorting facilities.